# XeLaTex - fontawesome: compiles without errors, but doesn't show symbols

Tags: xetex, luatex, miktex, fontawesome

I have trouble using fontawesome symbols with XeLaTex. Set up MikTex 2.9 on Windows 8.1 from scratch. Fontawesome installed properly.
When I try to use fontawesome symbols with XeLaTex I don't get any errors or warnings, but the symbols simply don't show up in my document. Using LuaLaTex everything is fine.

Example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faTwitter Some Text \faLinkedin
\end{document}`
```

LuaLaTex: compiles with no errors or warnings to

[image]

XeLaTex: compiles with no errors or warnings to

[image]

To make sure, that there are no problems with the management of local fonts I tried to use a locally installed otf as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\setmainfont{Myriad Pro Light}
\begin{document}
\faTwitter Some Text \faLinkedin
\end{document}
```

This way XeLateX is using the correct locally installed font, but it is still not showing the fontawesome symbols. Everything is alright with LuaLaTex.

Tried to re-install the fontawesome package, resfresh FNDB, update formats. Had a look at font.conf. All of it to no avail...

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On miktex xetex seems to find the type1 variant of the font. Try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\newfontfamily{\FA}{fontawesome.otf}

\begin{document}
\faTwitter Some Text  \faLinkedin
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even the opentype font font is found on MiKTeX.

Comment: thank you so much... the \newfontfamily did the trick... yay! :)

Comment: While your workaround didn’t work for me, your diagnosis was correct. I renamed the `MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\type1\public\fontawesome\FontAwesome.pfb` to something else, then everything works fine.